What are the $f$- invariant measures?
Here is a part of the question that I am thinking about:
Let $X$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2.$ Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix with real entries, determinant 1, and which does not have finite order. Define
$f: X \to X$ by $$\frac{A(v)}{|A(v)|}.$$ First let $$\begin{matrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & 1/a
\end{matrix}$$ for $a > 0.$
1- What are the fixed points of $f$ when $f$ is defined using this matrix A?
2- What are the $f$- invariant measures?
3- Suppose $B$ is a matrix similar to $A.$ What are the invariant measures for the map  $g: X \to X$ by $$\frac{B(v)}{|B(v)|}?$$
My thoughts are:
1- the fixed points are 0 and $\infity.$ Am I correct?
2- what is the importance of the determinant being 1 here? What is the importance of not having finite order?what is the importance of the unit circle?
3- how can I find the $f$- invariant measures? Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Not a complete answer. Just calculating the fixed points for $f$ in case $A=\left( \begin{smallmatrix} a&0\\ 0&1/a \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.
When
$f\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x\\ y \end{smallmatrix}\right) 
= \left(\begin{smallmatrix} x\\ y \end{smallmatrix}\right) $
we have
$\left( \begin{smallmatrix} a&0\\ 0&1/a \end{smallmatrix} \right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x\\ y \end{smallmatrix}\right)
=\lambda \left(\begin{smallmatrix} x\\ y \end{smallmatrix}\right)
$
where $\lambda = \sqrt{(ax)^2+(y/a)^2}$. This is an eigenvalue/eigenvector problem. The eigenvalues/vectors for $A$ are $a$ corresponding to the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} v\\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $v\neq0$ and $1/a$ corresponding to the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0\\ w \end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $w\neq0$.
Checking the formula for $\lambda$. For the eigenvalue $\lambda=a$ we need $a=\sqrt{(av)^2+(0/a)^2}=|av|,$ since $a>0$ this means $|v|=1.$ Similarly, for the eigenvalue $\lambda=1/a$ we need $1/a=\sqrt{(a0)^2+(w/a)^2}=|w/a|,$ since $a>0$ this means $|w|=1.$
So the fixed points for $f$ are  $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} \pm 1\\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0\\ \pm 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

why you thought of as an eigenvalue problem? why $Av = \lambda v?$

As a first step, I always look for a related problem I know I can solve.
